# How to call CreateProcessW correctly?

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

Here is my code:

```
from ctypes import *
WORD = c_ushort
DWORD = c_ulong
LPBYTE = POINTER(c_ubyte)
LPTSTR = POINTER(c_char)
HANDLE = c_void_p
DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010
class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("cb", DWORD),
    ("lpReserved", LPTSTR),
    ("lpDesktop", LPTSTR),
    ("lpTitle", LPTSTR),
    ("dwX", DWORD),
    ("dwY", DWORD),
    ("dwXSize", DWORD),
    ("dwYSize", DWORD),
    ("dwXCountChars", DWORD),
    ("dwYCountChars", DWORD),
    ("dwFillAttribute",DWORD),
    ("dwFlags", DWORD),
    ("wShowWindow", WORD),
    ("cbReserved2", WORD),
    ("lpReserved2", LPBYTE),
    ("hStdInput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdOutput", HANDLE),
    ("hStdError", HANDLE),
    ]
class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("hProcess", HANDLE),
    ("hThread", HANDLE),
    ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
    ("dwThreadId", DWORD),
    ]


kernel32 = windll.kernel32
class debugger():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def load(path_to_exe):
        creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
        startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
        processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
        startupinfo.dwFlags = 0x1
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = 0x0
        startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
        if kernel32.CreateProcessA(path_to_exe,None,None,None,None,creation_flags,None,None,byref(startupinfo),byref(processinfo)):
            print("[*] Process launched")
            print("[*] PID: %d" % (PROCESS_INFORMATION.dwProcessId))
        else:
            print("[*] Error: 0x%08x." % (kernel32.GetLastError()))

debugger.load("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe")
```

I'm actually following along Gray hat python right now, and I'm converting this code to python2.7 as I read it.

Whenever I run it, it goes to the error: [*] Error: 0x000003e6.

but when my friend try this code in his computer, he can get:
[*]We have successfully launched the process!
[*]PID: 1208

and both our systems are 64-bit windows7.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you both have 64-bit Python installed?  `.argtypes` and `.restype` should be set on your function or `ctypes` defaults to passing 32-bit parameters.  On 64-bit Python that truncates your `byref` values, which are 64-bit pointers.

As a reference, here's a fully tested version that works on Python 2 and 3, both 32- and 64-bit:

```
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import BYTE, WORD, DWORD, LPWSTR, LPCWSTR, HANDLE, LPVOID, BOOL

LPBYTE = POINTER(BYTE)

DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010
STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001
SW_HIDE = 0

class STARTUPINFOW(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('cb', DWORD),
                ('lpReserved', LPWSTR),
                ('lpDesktop', LPWSTR),
                ('lpTitle', LPWSTR),
                ('dwX', DWORD),
                ('dwY', DWORD),
                ('dwXSize', DWORD),
                ('dwYSize', DWORD),
                ('dwXCountChars', DWORD),
                ('dwYCountChars', DWORD),
                ('dwFillAttribute', DWORD),
                ('dwFlags', DWORD),
                ('wShowWindow', WORD),
                ('cbReserved2', WORD),
                ('lpReserved2', LPBYTE),
                ('hStdInput', HANDLE),
                ('hStdOutput', HANDLE),
                ('hStdError', HANDLE)]

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('hProcess', HANDLE),
                ('hThread', HANDLE),
                ('dwProcessId', DWORD),
                ('dwThreadId', DWORD)]

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('nLength', DWORD),
                ('lpSecurityDescriptor', LPVOID),
                ('bInheritHandle', BOOL)]

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
LPSTARTUPINFOW = POINTER(STARTUPINFOW)
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)

def boolcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return None

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
CreateProcess = kernel32.CreateProcessW
CreateProcess.argtypes = (LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,
                          BOOL, DWORD, LPVOID, LPCWSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOW, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION)
CreateProcess.restype = BOOL
CreateProcess.errcheck = boolcheck

def load(path_to_exe):
    creation_flags = DEBUG_PROCESS
    startupinfo = STARTUPINFOW()
    processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
    startupinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    startupinfo.cb = sizeof(startupinfo)
    CreateProcess(path_to_exe, None, None, None, False, creation_flags, None, None, byref(startupinfo), byref(processinfo))
    print('[*] Process launched')
    print('[*] PID: {}'.format(processinfo.dwProcessId))

load(r'C:\windows\system32\calc.exe')
```

Note that the OP used `SW_HIDE` and `DEBUG_PROCESS` which will not show the process window and also terminate the debugged process when the Python process exits, so only the success message will be visible.  Pause at the end of the script with some `input()` and the process will be viewable in Task Manager.

Comment: thanks for help,I can create new process by using your code.but I do have 64-bit Python installed before